# Can awStats be given log files of other servers?

Tags: logging, open-source, web-analytics, awstats

From what I understand awStats would be installed on a particular server and the path would be set to your respective log file and would be processed.

What i would like to know is, can awStats be installed on a non server machine and given log files from a foreign server and analyzed?

Answer (score 0):

of course. in fact that's how most people analyse their web logs - by copying them to non-live machine and running awstats there.

and in awstats.conf you can use Unix pipe in LogFile directive so for example:

```
LogFile="ssh httpd@yourserver.com cat /var/log/apache2/httpd.log|"
```

should work.